# deleting/updating select element options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material ui select element with added functionality such as multiple selection with checkbox, my question is, is there a way to delete and update name from select element itself ?
for example: by clicking the pen next to 'Oliver Hansen' i could update that name or by clicking recycle bin delete that name ?

code to try:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-forked-nrm6z4?file=/src/App.js

```js
code:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import { MenuProps, useStyles, options } from "./utils";

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("vals", event.target);
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelected(value);
    console.log("values", selected);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="mutiple-select-label">Multiple Select</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="mutiple-select-label"
        multiple
        variant="outlined"
        value={selected || []}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderValue={(selected) => selected}
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Checkbox checked={selected?.includes(option)} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={option.title}>{option}</ListItemText>
            <DeleteIcon />
            <ListItemIcon>
              <CreateIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>

      <p>{selected}</p>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: any advice is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you need to store your `options` in a state, and on the `delete` button you can `stopPropagation` and `filter` options of clicked option, and the same you can do to the `edit`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import { MenuProps, useStyles, options as rawOptions } from "./utils";

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(rawOptions)

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("vals", event.target);
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelected(value);
    console.log("values", selected);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel id="mutiple-select-label">Multiple Select</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="mutiple-select-label"
        multiple
        variant="outlined"
        value={selected || []}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderValue={(selected) => selected}
        MenuProps={MenuProps}
      >
        {options.map((option, index) => (
          <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Checkbox checked={selected?.includes(option)} />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={option.title}>{option}</ListItemText>
            <DeleteIcon onClick={(e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
              setOptions(options.filter(o => o !== option))
              console.log('run');
            }} />
            <ListItemIcon>
              <CreateIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>

      <p>{selected}</p>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit Material UI Multiple Select with select all option (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare another piece of state to represent `options`.

```
const [selectOptions, setSelectOptions] = useState(options);
```

Then from inside each element you could handle the delete or name change options by setting that state. For example, to handle deleting the element from the list:

```
  {options.map((option, index) => (
...
            <DeleteIcon
            onClick={() =>
                setSelectOptions((opts) => {
                const newOpts = [...opts]; //create a shallow copy of selectOptions
                newOpts.splice(index, 1); //remove the element at the current index
                return newOpts;
                })
            }
            />
...
  ))}
```

This will push an update to the UI only. Additionally, if you wanted to also forever mutate the array options that you're importing from './utils', you could just include code inside the `onClick` event handler to make those updates as well.

Handling user input for changing the name is a little trickier, since you will also need to include a conditionally-displayed `<TextField />` or similar for the user to perform the edits needed. You would probably also need to track some sort of state related to the editing process as well, something like:

```
const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
```

And then using that to conditionally render a text field.

```
<CreateIcon onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)} />
{isEditing && <TextField />}
```

That should hopefully get you started, from there you can also conditionally render a submit button, give it a `onClick` callback to update the `selectOptions` state, set the `isEditing` state back to false, and potentially mutate the original options array.